# MS Access Database with Java Relative Path

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

I have the following code

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ= D:\\work folder\\netzeus\\Project - Optimo (Phase 1)\\DB\\DonorsDetail.mdb");
```

The issue with the above code is the application will not be portable. So what I did was

1. I copied the database file into the project folder
2. I tried to change path in the `getConnection` to

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=DonorsDetail.mdb");

unfortunately That didn't work. Is there a way to set the relative path ? and how do I do that ?

Comment: I don't think the path can be relative, as I think it be relative to the driver not the application. Best thing might be to use File#getAbsolutePath (or similar) and use the resulting String instead

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998802/how-to-give-a-relative-path-in-java-for-databse-so-that-when-we-put-it-on-other

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Is it safe to put the db file into the build folder ? then the path would be based on the working directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `File` to generate an absolute path `String`, for example...

```
File dbFile = new File("DonorsDetail.mdb");
String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
```

This would assume that `DonorsDetail.mdb` was relative to the application execution context (ie the working directory)

Comment: Wanted to use similar mechanism, thanks for showing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to connect to the database, I do it like:

```
String dbFileName = "D:/work folder/netzeus/Project - Optimo (Phase 1)/DB/DonorsDetail.mdb";//Using your database path
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
        "DBQ="+dbFileName+";";
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Try this. If you till get an error then check your spell and folder names.

**EDIT:**

As you want to do it portable you can put your database into `C:/` only. Just encrypt your database file and hardcode the password to open the database file like:

```
String dbFileName = "C:/DonorsDetail.mdb";
String password = "your_password";
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
    "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
    "Pwd="+password+";";
```

See [how to encrypt database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-HA010341664.aspx)

Comment: This is essentially what the OP is doing now and wants to avoid

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I think using this code his first issue "the application will not be portable" is solved.

Comment: How? `dbFileName` is an absolute path, which is not portable

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right. But if we change the path from "D:/work folder/netzeus/Project - Optimo (Phase 1)/DB/DonorsDetail.mdb" to "C:/DonorsDetail.mdb" then it will be ok.Because C:/ is the common to all.

Comment: Still no portable, what about Mac's and Linux based OS's?  What about those silly people (like me) who keep their applications on other drives other than C?  Hard coding the value in this way is not a viable solution...

Comment: No worries, hope I wasn't to terse...long day in the sun at the beach ;)